# Regex to FindAll chains of strings until a dot with python

Tags: python, regex

I need the regex expression gives to me the word before the : and all until a .
The right output will be

```
['Socios: Norberto Alejandro PERONACE, 16/8/1973', 'Joaquin: jaja']
```

Here is my code:

```
text = "Esc. 7, Fº 10, 14/1/2019, Esc. M. Paula Corallo, Reg. 1525, Socios: Norberto Alejandro PERONACE, 16/8/1973. Joaquin: jaja."

if re.findall(r":", text):
    print(re.findall(r"\w+: \w+.\Z", text))
else:
    print("Match not found")
```

Comment: And what's wrong with your code?

Comment: it's cut the output to the first word instead of continiuos to the dot @Sweeper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'\S+:[^.]+', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pmBQip/1)

**Details**

- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `:` - a colon
- `[^.]+` - 1+ non-dot chars.

See also the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/UUE6Tn).